# Pass parameters to lightning page in custom list view button

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, custom-button

I want to access lwc component from custom list button in related list. I created this custom list button with content source as URL to a lightning page. However when I include the parameters it is taking to the page but parameters are getting removed. Is there a way hold the parameters while navigating to a lightning page ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters must be specified with a [Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_namespaces.htm). If you're developing for your own org, use `c` as the namespace.

```
/lightning/n/New_Contact_Roles?c__opptyId=23223
```

Also, check out the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigate_add_params.htm).

> `state` parameters must be namespaced. For example, a managed package with the namespace `abc` with a parameter `accountId` is represented as `abc__accountId`. The namespace for custom components is `c__`. Parameters without a namespace are reserved for Salesforce use. This namespace restriction is introduced under a critical update in Winter ’19 and enforced in Summer ’19.

Note that this is a *double*-underscore (`__`), not just one.